# Diawi - This request requires an access token, but none was provided

Tags: ios, beta-testing, diawi

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqPsf.png

I have this problem this morning, but I tried a lot time. It always failed. I using Chrome for upload

Comment: I changed to Safari and successfully upload.

Comment: Please use TestFlight for Testing

Comment: This is old problem, I found the solution. Right now, I am using TestFlight, any tks alot